# Unity - Running Android app with 10000 small mp3 files

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, text-to-speech

I am making a Unity dictionary app. It contains 10000 pronunciation mp3 files.
Every time the user selects one English word, it will automatically pronounce the words.

I can successfully install the apk file to my mobile phone. Unfortunately, it failed and stopped to run. It may be due to out of memory!

Total apk file size is around 65M, which is ok to me. What is the best way to handle 10000 mp3 files in my case?

Comment: you should check the exception stacktrace in the logcat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: It crashed in mobile phone only, not in Unity. Is it still possible to check the exception in the logcat?

Comment: Yes logcat is only for your mobile device. Look up "debugging android".

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article:
http://blog.theknightsofunity.com/wrong-import-settings-killing-unity-game-part-2/

Maybe setting Load Type to Streaming can help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe keeping 10,000 media file in the app itself is not a good idea. As you said the APK size is 65MB it's very big for a simple app. I will recommend to keep those files in web and use URL in the app to download them at the beginning. after downloading save them to SD card or phone memory and access them from the storage location. It will not crash your app.

Comment: I want my app using offline for everyone. I think 65MB is ok for me. Any alternative to deal with 10000 mp3 files? How about if I combine every 1000 files to one mp3 file and run a specific time period in the file?

Comment: Yes it is ok, i have complete project that have total ~200MB files for Android. And it working correctly without freezes.

Comment: You can try one thing in manifest file you can write   <application ....    android:largeHeap="true"   ..>  maybe will fix your problem.